# How can I create a "global state" in react native so I can send a user input to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to take a user input(email) and send it to the password page for display. I am under impression by attempt below is not working because the input is local and cannot be seen by the password page? How should I go about this? Something with reduxes? Am I on the right track?

If you guys need more code let me know, I appreciate any help more than you know!

Email page

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#A2A2A2',
      inputValue: '', //add state here
    };
  }

  updateInputValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        inputValue: event.target.value
    });
}

navigateToCreatePasswordScreen = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("CreatePassword", {
    inputValue: this.state.inputValue,
  });
};

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        
        {/* Email Input */}
      <Container style = {styles.emailInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel >
            <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>Email Address</Label>
                <Input
                value = {this.state.inputValue}
                onChange={(this.updateInputValue)}                
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#F7018D'})}               
                onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
                />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </Container>

 
      <View style={styles.containerBottom}>   
      <ContinueButton
       onPress={() => this.navigateToCreatePasswordScreen()}
      /> 
      </View>
```

password page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import ContinueButton from '../components/ContinueButton';
import BackArrow from '../components/BackArrow';
import { Container, Content, Header, Form, Input, Item, Label, } from 'native-base';

export default class CreatePasswordPage extends Component {

  /* Colors Input label*/
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#A2A2A2'};}
  
  render() {

    const {inputValue} = this.props.route.params;

    return (
        <View>
       
      <View>   
    <Text style={styles.caption}>{inputValue}</Text> 
      </View>
        
        </View>
```

Comment: You can use something like redux (or another state management library), or React context, but also the simplest way to accomplish this is to just maintain this particular state at the closest common parent of the two components and pass the state and a setter function down to each component as necessary.

Comment: Okay, I like that idea. Thank you for the insight! Do you happen to know an example I could find online or some good documentation for such! I know I could figure this out eventually but you would be helping me out big time if you could point me in a good direction!

Comment: I think this would be a good little tutorial to run through: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @JustinPriede Why did you tag it with react-redux? if you used that then you didn't need to ask this question.

Comment: Because I know you are able to use redux with it, hoping someone from that community could point me in the right direction on how to if thats the best option!