# Could someone explain how to determine my parent file in order to lift a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am trying to lift a state up so I can use it across some pages, I am struggling to figure out where I should reference the states, as I am unclear where my parent would be here. This is my first time designing an app so my file directory is probably not organized like it should be! I have attached a picture of my file directory as the code for my app.js so you can see why I dont just reference them there. Or maybe I can?

What is the best way to go about this? Any insight is appreciated a lot more than you know! Thank you.

I am trying to take an input from the SignUpEmail page, update its state, and send it to my CreatePassword page.

I feel I did not do the best explaining myself! For more context, visit my last post -> [How can I create a "global state" in react native so I can send a user input to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544097/how-can-i-create-a-global-state-in-react-native-so-i-can-send-a-user-input-to?noredirect=1#comment115881531_65544097)

app.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
 
  createHomeStack = () =>
  <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component= {SplashScreenPage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component= {WelcomePage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component= {LoginPage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUpEmail" component= {SignUpEmailPage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="CreatePassword" component= {CreatePasswordPage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="PhoneVerification" component= {PhoneVerificationPage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {HomePage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="YourName" component= {YourNamePage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="ProfilePicUpload" component= {ProfilePicUploadPage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="LikedPage" component= {LikedPage} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.welcomeScreen}>
       {this.createHomeStack()}
      </View>
  
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The file structure doesn't matter, your JSX is what puts components as children; just pass the state and a method to change it as prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when lifting state you select the closest common ancestor in the React virtual DOM tree to all the components that needs access to the "shared state". Your *actual* file structure is irrelevant.

From your snippet `App` looks to *be* that common ancestor for `SignUpEmailPage` and `CreatePasswordPage` components since it is rendering both, though how you decide to pass the "common" state and callbacks to update it is another exercise.

You can use local component state in `App`, create a context provider and wrap the common ancestor (each component can subscribe to the context), or you can go full-blown app-state management with something like redux. It depends on your shared common state needs.

Comment: Thank you! So, I will want to be referencing this state a decent amount of times throughout the app. I think I should use redux? Or is that an overkill type of option? If I should use the simpler version of using the local component state in app, could you point me somewhere that could elaborate on that? Unsure how to go about creating a context provider, I can figure it out, but you would be saving me some time! Thank you again for your insight!!!

Comment: @JustinPriede To be honest I often refer back to the official react docs: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) are good and have useful examples. [React-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) is an abstraction built on top of the Context API, but has a bit steeper learning curve and more moving parts. I think for just storing some state to pass from one page to another I'd recommend the "lifting state" method as that'll likely feel the most natural to you. When your needs expand then you can check out the others.

Comment: Noted! Appreciate all of your time:)

Comment: @JustinPriede Oh, just caught the "decent amount of times throughout the app" bit, sure, if you feel like giving redux a try go for it. I'd check out [Redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) then. It's yet another abstraction over redux (and react-redux) that attempts to deal with the boilerplately-ness of redux. Redux is great, so please don't let my comments about it scare you away, I just like for people to be prepared for it.